# setInterval для сканирования БД

Tags: ajax, php

Привет всем. У этого моего супер-пупер-самого-лучшего-мессенджера-в-мире возник вопрос. Насколько часто нужно вызывать функцию аджакс для сканирования БД в поисках "А НЕ НАПИСАЛ ЛИ КТО НОВОЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ?". Ну, там, каждые 500мс или реже. Как это устроено на практике? И еще вопрос - есть ли на сей день реализация обратной связи, когда сервер сам дает знать браузеру, что юзеру ПРИШЛО НОВОЕ СООБЩЕНИЕ? С ув.Deus.

Comment: long polling, short polling, websockets (для последнего на пхп нужно костыль ставить)

Comment: ещё server side events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подобных задач использую [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) ,
на серверной стороне - `node.js`, на клиенте - `javascript`
обработка события происходит по мере его возникновения, т.е. не надо интервально что-либо сканить

Answer (score 5):

*И Вам день добрый.*

Данную задачу можно реализовать задачу с помощью **jQuery** и **php**.

**Решение:**

Проверить получил ли пользователь сообщения мы будем через **php**, а запрос на проверку, мы будем делать через **jQuery**, функцией *setInterval()*. И еще один нюанс, все *НЕ* прочитанные сообщения у нас буду равны столбику в бд **activ=1**, тобишь, не прочитанные.

**Кодинг**

Создадим проверку на **php:**

*Назовем этот файлик new_mess.php*

```
<?php
session_start();
$zap = $_POST['zap']; //Переменная для запроса :)
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE login='".$_SESSION['login']."' AND    active='1'");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
  echo "new_mess";
}
?>
```

**Я так полагая, что у Вас работает на сессиях мессенджер**

А теперь отправляем запросы на проверку каждые *10 секунд* на **jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    $.post('new_mess.php',{zap:'zap'},function(data){
      if(data == 'new_mess'){
        alert('У Вас новое сообщение, читайте его ^_^');
      }
    });
  },10000);
});
```

*Ну, вот так, как то:) Надеюсь, помог.*

Comment: Чётко изложил) Аж глаз радует

Comment: @Сергей Кашурин, стараюсь))

Comment: @IamS, вот это ответ! Только  у меня все уже написано, и намного сложнее запросы, а вопрос-то был вот про эти ваши 10 секунд. По-моему вы многовато задали...

Comment: @Deus, я показ полное решение задачи, возьмите то что вам нужно, в чем проблема?

Comment: @IamS, дык вопрос был про 500мс и про comet. )))

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#example_1").everyTime(1000, function(i) {
 $(this).text(i);
});
```

Только внутрь `Ajax` вставь, и время можно вполне до 100 снизить, если нужно чтоб почти в реальном времени, если нет, и секунды вполне хватит. Ещё можно использовать [cron](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/php/cron.php).

Comment: + jabber http://blog.ht-expert.ru/2010/01/10/%D0%BC%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-jabberphpajax/

Comment: @Сергей Кашурин, это все требует незаурядного напряжения мозговой ткани. Спасибо, буду разбираться.

Answer (score 1):

А так, думаю, лучше выбирать интервал, исходя из средней активности чата. Т.е., если в среднем у вас за минуту отправляется 5 сообщений, то не надо посылать запрос каждые 500мс, а разделить время задержки

здержка = времяСтатистики/среднееКоличествоСообщенийЗаВремяСтатистики
ВрменемСтатистики может быть минута, 30 секунд и все такое.

Comment: @iamsalnikov, только что погуглил, - запросов на сервер может быть много, я должен программным путем реализовать очередь запросов? Например, если юзер отправляет сообщение, оно должно помещаться в очередь. Я правильно понял?